# Can someone explain what the xml:space attribute is used for in XHTML5?

Tags: xml, html

I was wondering what does the xml:space attribute do and what are it's values in XHTML5. and does the xml:space attribute have any restrictions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such a thing as XHTML5. If by "XHTML5", you mean HTML5, than:

> The XML specification also allows the use of the xml:space attribute in the XML namespace on any element in an XML document. **This attribute has no effect on HTML elements**, as the default behavior in HTML is to preserve whitespace.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html

Now, for XML documents in general, xml:space specifies the way the spaces are handled. Two possible values are `default` and `preserve`. Default will trim all spaces to a single space (except in CDATA). Preserve will keep the number of consecutive spaces as is.

In HTML, spaces are always preserved. It allows for example to use `<pre/>` tag, or `white-space` property in CSS.